# Script bash поиск PIDа

Tags: bash, linux

Имеется следующее задание:

> Сгенерировать следующую информацию о m
> (m>2) процессах системы, имеющих
> значение идентификатора больше
> заданного n: флаг — сведения о
> процессе, статус, PID, PPID,
> приоритет, использованное время и имя
> программы.

искал долго но так и не нашел как обычными командами вывести данную информацию, решил что нужно использовать баш скрипт:

*1.Записать все пиды пользователя в файл
2.Задать число n
3.Произвести сортировку и вывести на экраны PIDы больших n
 1. Вывести информацию по пидам.* 
 2. Элемент списка

Помогите реализовать данную программу, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: `ps aux` вам в помощь

Comment: я там изучил все, он не выдает требуемого, конкретно я не знаю какой командой задать число n и чтоб при этом пиды выдавались больше этого числа

Comment: Так `ps aux` нужно использовать с другими утилитами. Можно `grep` и `sort` задействовать - они позволят отсортировать список процессов, ну, и вычленить с нужными PID. Еще чисто гипотетически можно вручную пройтись по виртуальной файловой системе /proc - в ней хранятся все параметры процессов, и их можно оттуда вычленить. А PID можно банально завести как переменную шелл-скрипта.

Comment: понять бы эту систему, grep и sort, пробовал задействовать, но там тоже ничего путного нет,  "/proc - в ней хранятся все параметры процессов, и их можно оттуда вычленить. А PID можно банально завести как переменную шелл-скрипта " а вот с этим я не знаю как работать

Comment: не совсем понял задание, но по pid'ам

      ps aux | awk '{if ($2 > 30) print $0}'

Answer (score 1):

вот на bash, без awk, sed,grep:

```
ps xawwwwwwww -o pid,ppid,priority,etime,comm |
    while read pid ppid priority etime comm;do 
          if ((pid>20));then 
                    echo $pid $ppid $priority $etime $comm;
          fi;
    done
```

вот если значения других полей обрабатывать не надо:

```
ps xawwwwwwww -o pid,ppid,priority,etime,comm |
    while read pid other;
         do if ((pid>20));then 
            echo $pid $other ;
         fi;
    done
```